# How do I modify uib-typeahead async google maps api example to show only cities?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, angular-ui-bootstrap

Apologies if this answer is already somewhere, but I looked through all similar questions and didn't see the exact issue.

I would like to simply modify UI-Bootstrap's beautifully working uib-typeahead 'Asynchronous Results' Example to show only cities (with state and country). http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

I'd like to see if it's possible to do this without including a  linking to the google maps api, which uib-typeahead is also NOT doing. In addition, I'd like to see if it's possible to do it on the front end, instead of using the back end with a developer key, although if this doesn't work, then I will default to that option.

I've tried modifying the 'params' object like this:

```
params: {
     address: val,
     sensor: false,
     types: (cities) // also tried types: ('cities') and types: (regions)
}
```

Is it possible to do this on the front end without a developer key?

Answer (score 0):

In the specified example [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) service is consumed and according to [Google Maps Geocoding API Request Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests) neither `type` nor `types` are supported.

Since [reverse geocoding response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#sample-request) contains among another properties also a `types` property you could consider to *filter results on the client side*. The following example demonstrates how to modify the provided examples to display only cities in results:

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false 
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      var items = response.data.results.filter(function(item){
           return isCityType(item);
      });

      return items.map(function(item){
        return item.formatted_address;
      });

    });
  };

  var isCityType = function(item) {
       var result = item.types.filter(function(t){
          return t == "locality" ||  t == "administrative_area_level_3";
       });
       return result.length > 0;
  };
```

**[Modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5zTYqGHe5e2m34aAPCop)**